# store procedure nulls or zero value in column

Tags: stored-procedures

i have  a store procedure,its meant for updating a table,when i execute it,it brings out nulls or zero values for a some columns.this is the logic used

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#exxPresessions_john') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #exxPresessions_john

SELECT c.claim_id,
       c.completed_date,
       wp.createdon,
       COUNT(DISTINCT wp.WebSessionId) AS websessions
INTO #exxPresessions_john
FROM dbo.web_PageviewsID wp WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN #CliamID_john c WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON c.claim_id = wp.claimid
WHERE ClaimType IS NOT NULL
  AND c.completed_date > wp.createdon 
GROUP BY 
   claim_id,
   completed_date,
   createdon
ORDER BY claim_id;

CREATE INDEX idx_index2 ON #WebPresessions_nosa (claim_id);
```

this is the Condition
`completed_date > created_date` 
.it returns NULL as completed_date is NULL or Zero

i tried this but it did not work
`and ISNULL (c.completed_date,0)> wp.createdon`

Comment: `ISNULL (c.completed_date,0)` Why you are setting the date value as 0?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more condition like this:

```
WHERE ClaimType IS NOT NULL
AND c.completed_date is not null    --Removes the null completed_date  
  AND c.completed_date > wp.createdon
```